# Diable auto-trim in SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Several times when troubleshooting my SQL queries, I run into a problem where there is extra space in one of my columns which breaks a comparison.  Because SSMS 2008 auto-trims those columns, *I don't see the problem.*  It makes troubleshooting take much longer.

Is there any way to disable this auto-trimming?

Comment: When you say SSMS auto-trims the columns, do you mean in the grid results panel?

Comment: Yes, in the results panel (finally have time to deal with this issue again).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this through the SSMS options, but I discovered a workaround: it appears that SSMS does not autotrim if all values in the column are of a string type. For instance, the following will display with ten spaces in front of the numeric value:

```
select
    space(10) + cast(2000 as varchar)
        as PaddedValue
```

Without the cast, the spaces do not appear in the results grid:

```
select
    space(10) + 2000
        as TrimmedValue
```